# Calling a function from within a function in Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, call, function-call

My script contains three functions:

**get_file()** : returns the list of filenames (file_list) with all .xls files in a specific directory

**data_conversion()** : processes the data contained in the files from file_list

**work_flow()** : calls get_file() and data_conversion()

```
def work_flow():
    x = get_file() #returns list of .xls files
    y = [filepath + item for item in x] #add filepath
    counter = 0 #to check how many files are processed
        for file in y:
        try:
            data_conversion()
            counter +=1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print counter, 'Files processed.'
    print '-------------------------------'
    return()
work_flow()
```

The problem is as following: If I add the code contained in workflow() without the function to the end of the script, everything runs just fine. However, if I nest it in a function, I get the following error message:

**"global variable data_conversion not defined"**

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

EDIT: Thank you for the help so far. I checked the code, and **the problem appears to be within data_conversion().** If I only include a print function in data_conversion(), everything runs smoothly. So here is the snippet from data_conversion() that seems to be the problem:

```
def data_conversion():
    print("Executes")
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file) #LOOKS LIKE THE PROBLEM IS HERE?
    print("Does not execute")

    return()
```

And here is the code from get_file():

```
# CREATES A LIST WITH ALL .XLS FILES IN FILEPATH

def get_file():
    path = filepath
    file_list = list()
    listing = os.listdir(path)
    for infile in listing:
        if infile.endswith('.xls'):
            file_list.append(infile)
    return(file_list)
```

I am quite confident that the answer is close, but I am so stuck...

Comment: It's unclear without seeing the whole file.

Comment: I added code from the other functions - this helped me to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your function `data_conversion` is defined **after** you call `work_flow`. That's why you get this error.

Move the definition of `data_conversation` above and it will work.

Better yet: do not call functions in the core of your script, but call them at the end, using this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_flow()
```

This will ensure that all your functions are defined before you call them, and will allow you to import your module from other modules without executing the code.

Comment: Valuable advice - will do so in the future. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. It can happen if the definition of  data_conversation is after the call or you have miss-spelt it's definition.

Comment: It appears that the problem is within data_conversion() -> see above

Answer (score 0):

I got it - the file never got called by the function! hence:

```
def data_conversion(file): #instead of ()
    .....
    return()
```

and

```
def work_flow():
    .....
    .....
    data_conversion(file) #instead of ()
    .....
    return()
```

did the trick. Thanks for your help!